# WinXP: File Record Segment nnnn is unreadable?

Tags: windows-xp, check-disk

I'm pretty sure that the drive is toast, except for the fact that this error is only showing up on one partition (it's out of a Dell computer, and has a couple of Dell partitions, which boot and work fine.)

I've already purchased another hard drive, and re-installed WinXP, but when I re-connect this drive and reboot, I'm getting thousands of these errors.

Is there any chance of recovering any files off this?  Should I prevent XP from trying to resolve the problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so after about 6 hours of grinding away at the disk, when I finally was able to log into the machine, I had an E: drive (the D: drive is the DVD).

Except that I got a warning that windows had detected a new piece of hardware, and needed to reboot.

I let it, and when it came back I still had an E: drive, but when I tried to access it, I was asked if I wanted to format it.

At this point, I booted with the [system rescue disk](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download), and was able to mount both the new and the old disk.  Note:  you can use the mount command to mount an NTFS partion read-only, but have to use ntfs-3g to mount one R/W.  I mounted the bad partion R/O, and the new disk R/W.

I was then able to copy over most of the contents of the bad disk to the new disk with cp -r

Answer (score 4):

Get as much off as you can before using anything to try and fix it.

Before running chkdsk, I'd avise running [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) to try and recover the lost sectors (chkdsk will just mark them bad).

Comment: After it finished, when I try to access the disk, it informs me that it needs to be formatted.

Comment: Apparently you had dead sectors in the file system itself, which doesn't surprise me if you were gettign 1000's of that error. :( That's why I suggested getting as much off before running it.